# Unable to use RestContext in VSCode

Tags: apex, rest-api, apexrest, vs-code

I had to start using VSCode from IntelliJ (Illuminate Cloud). Surprisingly, all my services are throwing compilation errors.

```
@HttpGet
global static list<Lead_Behaviour__c> getLeadByParams() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;

    Map<String, String> params = req.params;
    String lastName = params.get('LastName');
    String leadId = params.get('Id');

    List<Lead_Behaviour__c> leadBehaviorList = [Select Id, Last_Name__c, Actions__c from Lead_Behaviour__c where Id =: leadId];
    return leadBehaviorList;
}
```

For example, in the above code, getting errors related to RestContext.

```
"message": "Non static field cannot be referenced from a static context: request from the type System.RestContext"
```

This was working fine in IntelliJ before. Am I missing something related to version or so?? Followed all the same steps mentioned while installing salesforce extensions for VSCode. My VSCode version is 1.44.2 and am using Mac.

Thanks!

Comment: Intellij does not supports SFDC OOB so you must be using an extension. If you are using illuminated cloud, it compiles system symbol table. If you are using source format it usually works seamlessly. What is your project structure? Also, is this error coming while deploying?

Comment: Also, please make sure you do not have a class named RestContext created in the apex classes

Comment: Please clarify in which context you're receiving the error message. Are you trying to deploy using SFDX source deploy?

Comment: @manjit5190 There is no RestContext apex class named. This is a new project created and which I am trying on VSCode. As of now, I have placed everything in force-app/main/default/classes. 
Also, this error is coming even before deployment!

Comment: Okay, I would suggest authorizing the org and then try deploying. The Salesforce errors in VS Code do not go away until you deploy. Can be a false positive.

Comment: yeah.. I did authorize and deployed again. Its working now. Strange one! 
Thanks @manjit5190